# Ansible, merge dictionaries into once

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have this example yaml files (haproxy.yml):

```
---
rules:
  aa:
    PHP53:
      - url: php53-1-aa.my-example.com
    PHP55:
      - url: php55-1-aa.my-example.com
    PHP56:
      - url: php56-1-aa.my-example.com
      - url: php56-2-aa.my-example.com
      - url: php56-3-aa.my-example.com
    PHP72:
      - url: php72-1-aa.my-example.com
      - url: php72-2-aa.my-example.com
      - url: php72-3-aa.my-example.com
  bb:
    PHP53:
      - url: php53-1-bb.my-example.com
      - url: php53-2-bb.my-example.com
      - url: php53-3-bb.my-example.com

    PHP55:
      - url: php55-1-bb.my-example.com
    PHP56:
      - url: php56-1-bb.my-example.com
      - url: php56-2-bb.my-example.com
      - url: php56-3-bb.my-example.com
    PHP72:
      - url: php72-1-bb.my-example.com
      - url: php72-2-bb.my-example.com
      - url: php72-3-bb.my-example.com
  cc:
    PHP55:
      - url: php55-1-cc.my-example.com
    PHP56:
      - url: php56-1-cc.my-example.com
      - url: php56-2-cc.my-example.com
      - url: php56-3-cc.my-example.com
...
```

I use this playbook to load this file :

```
---
- name: 'stack-example'
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: 'include'
      include_vars:
        file: 'haproxy.yml'

    - set_fact:
        try: '{{ try|default({}) | combine(item.value) }}'
      loop: '{{ lookup("dict", rules) }}'

    - debug:
        var: try
```

All the files is two explain and reproduce my problem :-)

I need to use `set_fact` to work on my variable.

My main goal is to merge/group all PHP** into one group.
This is an example of what I need, I try a lot of thing with `combine` `map` `lookup`but nothing give me the result I expect.

I try to have this:

```
{
  "PHP53": [
      { "url": "php53-1-aa.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php53-1-bb.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php53-2-bb.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php53-3-bb.my-example.com" }
  ],
  "PHP55": [
      { "url": "php55-1-aa.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php55-1-bb.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php55-1-cc.my-example.com" }
  ],
  "PHP56": [
      { "url": "php56-1-aa.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php56-2-aa.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php56-3-aa.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php56-1-bb.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php56-2-bb.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php56-3-bb.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php56-1-cc.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php56-2-cc.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php56-3-cc.my-example.com" },
  ],
  "PHP72": [
      { "url": "php72-1-aa.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php72-2-aa.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php72-3-aa.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php72-1-bb.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php72-2-bb.my-example.com" },
      { "url": "php72-3-bb.my-example.com" }
  ]
}
```

If someone have an idea to do this ?
Thank a lot for your help
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task below does it

```
- set_fact:
    rules_grouped: "{{ rules_grouped|
                       default({})|
                       combine({item.0: item.1|json_query('[].value')|flatten})
                       }}"
  loop: "{{ rules|
            dict2items|
            json_query('[*].value')|
            map('dict2items')|list|flatten|
            groupby('key')
            }}"
```

To learn how the loop works put it into debug and add the filters step by step.

```
   - debug
       msg: "{{ rules|
                dict2items
                }}"

   - debug
       msg: "{{ rules|
                dict2items|
                json_query('[*].value')
                }}"

   - debug
       msg: "{{ rules|
                dict2items|
                json_query('[*].value')|
                map('dict2items')|list|flatten
                }}"

   - debug
       msg: "{{ rules|
                dict2items|
                json_query('[*].value')|
                map('dict2items')|list|flatten|
                groupby('key')
                }}"
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank a new times for your help :-) A new times your solution is what I expect. I don't understand exactly how it's functionning but I will learn. Thank a lot.

Comment: It's quite easy to review the loop with debug. I've updated the answer.