# Merge multiple list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have a simple role which push template into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<interface>`.

Some of our routes are the same, so I'd like to factorize the routes with the help of roles vars & group/host vars.

I tried to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975784/ansible-merge-dictionnaries-into-once), but it expect a dict and I have a list of dict, and I'm not yet very comfortable with jinja filter at the moment.

This is my data structure:

```
management_default_gateway: '192.168.128.254'
management_interface: eth1
routes:
  - interface: "{{management_interface}}"
    route_array:
      - gateway: "{{management_default_gateway}}"
        network: 10.0.0.1/24
      - gateway: "{{management_default_gateway}}"
        network: 10.0.0.5/24
```

It works, even if there is other interfaces as the template loops over routes list (see below), and create one file per interface as expected.

`roles/routing/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: Template
  template:
    src: route.j2
    dest: "{{'-'.join((route_script_file,item.interface))}}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0640
  notify: networking restart
  with_list: "{{routes}}"
```

`roles/routing/templates/route.j2`:

```
{% for i in item.route_array %}
{{i.network ~ ' via ' ~ i.gateway ~ '\n'}}
{%- endfor %}
```

I'd like to have "standard" routes on the role vars folder (or `group_vars/all`), and add routes at group or host level.

So I tried to go with :
`roles/routing/vars/main.yml`:

```
default_routes:
  - interface: "{{management_interface}}"
    route_array:
      - gateway: "{{management_default_gateway}}"
        network: 10.0.0.1/24
      - gateway: "{{management_default_gateway}}"
        network: 10.0.0.5/24

routes_merged: "{{ default_routes + specific_routes }}"
```

`inventories/prod/group_vars/XXX.yml`:

```
specific_routes:
  - interface: "{{management_interface}}"
    route_array:
      - gateway: "{{management_default_gateway}}"
        network: 10.8.0.1/24
```

Then I got this result with debug var:

```
ok: [hostname] => {
    "routes": [
        {
            "interface": "eth1",
            "route_array": [
                {
                    "gateway": "192.168.128.254",
                    "network": "10.0.0.1/24"
                },
                {
                    "gateway": "192.168.128.254",
                    "network": "10.0.0.5/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "interface": "eth1",
            "route_array": [
                {
                    "gateway": "192.168.128.254",
                    "network": "10.8.0.1/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to have:

```
ok: [hostname] => {
    "routes": [
        {
            "interface": "eth1",
            "route_array": [
                {
                    "gateway": "192.168.128.254",
                    "network": "10.0.0.1/24"
                },
                {
                    "gateway": "192.168.128.254",
                    "network": "10.0.0.5/24"
                },
                {
                    "gateway": "192.168.128.254",
                    "network": "10.8.0.1/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to merge route_array by interface, in order to have only one template file generated by interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop with [groupby](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#groupby) does the job

```
- set_fact:
    routes: "{{ default_routes + specific_routes }}"
- set_fact:
    routes2: "{{ routes2|default([]) +
                [{'interface': item.1|map(attribute='interface')|list|first,
                  'route_array': item.1|map(attribute='route_array')|list|flatten}] }}"
  loop: "{{ routes| groupby('interface') }}"
- debug:
    var: routes2
```

gives

```
"routes2": [
    {
        "interface": "eth1", 
        "route_array": [
            {
                "gateway": "192.168.128.254", 
                "network": "10.0.0.1/24"
            }, 
            {
                "gateway": "192.168.128.254", 
                "network": "10.0.0.5/24"
            }, 
            {
                "gateway": "192.168.128.254", 
                "network": "10.8.0.1/24"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you, it generate a list of interfaces so my template task works in the same way.  
I didn't knew about groupby filter before, but it's very useful as I didn't had to write my own filter to do the job !